# Change css styles using jQuery Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background color of a button on hovering in and out of it. Please help me to make my jquery code work.

```
function onHoverIn(button) {
    $(button).css('background-color', 'rgba(193, 86, 10, 0.86)')
};
function onHoverOut(button) {
    $(button).css('background-color', 'rgba(26, 13, 3, 0.26)')
};
$("button").hover(onHoverIn(this), onHoverOut(this));
```

Reference - https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback `hover()` functions are already good friends with the `this` (jQuery Element Object reference), so all you need is to revoke the `$(this)`

```
function onHoverIn() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(193, 86, 10, 0.86)');
}
function onHoverOut() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(26, 13, 3, 0.26)');
}
$("button").hover(onHoverIn, onHoverOut);
```

You cannot pass **arguments** to arguments. That's what was wrong in your code:

```
.method( myFunz( this ) )
//       ^argument  ^argument :(
```

---

*How's that `$(this)` is available in those **Named Function Declarations**?*

[jQuery .hover() Docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> .hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
>
> **handlerIn**
>   Type: **Function**( Event eventObject )
>   A function to execute when the mouse pointer enters the element.
>
> **handlerOut**
>   Type: **Function**( Event eventObject )
>   A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.

so `.hover()` method accepts two **function** callbacks.

and exploring the jQuery code for the `.hover()` method:

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
    return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
},
```

you can clearly see that it `return`s `this` (the `Event eventObject`) to maintain methods chainability (`.hover().click().etc()`) and to make for you accessible the `this` (`Event eventObject`) who triggered the event.

---

If *(really, if)* all you need is a `:hover` that changes a `background-color`

### use CSS :)

```
button {
    background-color : rgba(193, 86, 10, 0.86);
}
button:hover {
    background-color : rgba(26, 13, 3, 0.26);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Have a demo, if you'd like: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sbxnf6p6/ (I was a few seconds behind you because I wanted to verify first...darn!) ;)

Comment: Thanks again. How is onHoverXxx  method given a reference to the button ?

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore a function is a function, so it's *given* the exact way as you'd do using `.hover(function(){ $(this).blabla(); });` where `this` is always `this` (the element who triggered the event).

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore to explain a bit more, jQuery Methods like `.hover()`,  `.css()`, `.click()` etc... name it (almost all methods, related to HTMLElements) internally, (to maintain Methods chainability) by default return `this;`, so that the `this` reference can be passed trough methods and accessed inside the function itself (without the need to specify some i.e: `that` argument in the fn arguments list.).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - The documentation says that handlerIn is like this `Function( Event eventObject )`. How does handlerIn get access to this ?

Comment: @HelloWorldNoMore instead of directly accessing a function callback like in `.hover(function(){ /*mouseenter stuff*/ }, function(){ /*mouseleave stuff*/ });` you simply replaced those `function(){}` with named function `onHoverIn`. Their use stays the same, no difference. Another example http://jsbin.com/foviji/2/js

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Thanks Roko. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way. When jQuery fires the callback, it will be called on the `button` object. so `this` will be the button.

```
function onHoverIn(button) {
    $(button).css('background-color', 'rgba(193, 86, 10, 0.86)')
};

function onHoverOut(button) {
    $(button).css('background-color', 'rgba(26, 13, 3, 0.26)')
};


$("button").hover(function() {
    onHoverIn(this)
},function() {
    onHoverOut(this)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to bind the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to be more explicit with your event bindings. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pf0Ldq5q/) example.

```
function onHoverIn() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(193, 86, 10, 0.86)');
}

function onHoverOut() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'rgba(26, 13, 3, 0.26)');
}

$(document).on('mouseover', 'button', onHoverIn);
$(document).on('mouseout', 'button', onHoverOut);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.